# Java date format

Tags: java, date, format, date-format

Have String str "May 23 2011 12:20:00", want to convert it to date such this:

```
Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")).parse(str);
```

It always gives me ParseException Unparsable date format: 'May 23 2011 12:20:00'.

Looked for similar issues, seems everything right.

What is wrong?

Comment: Works fine for me: `System.out.println((new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss")).parse("May 23 2011 12:20:00"));` prints `Mon May 23 12:20:00 IST 2011`

Comment: Perhaps you have an old version of Java. Which version are you using?

Comment: Java version 1.6.0 update 21, may be import is wrong? is it from import java.text.SimpleDateFormat and java.text.ParseException? date from java.util

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to additionally specify the **Locale**, when the default Locale of your VM is not an English one:

```
Date date = (new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd yyyy HH:mm:ss", Locale.US)).parse(str);
```

Answer (score 2):

[Works for me.!](http://ideone.com/SVmb4)

Comment: which java version you are using ?

Answer (score 1):

Try specifying locale while constructing SimpleDateFormat object.

Answer (score 1):

## tl;dr

```
LocalDateTime.parse(
    "May 23 2011 12:20:00" , 
    DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss" , Locale.US )
)
```

## Using java.time

The [accepted Answer by Andreas Krueger](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6135779/642706) is correct. You must specify a `Locale` to determine the human language used in translating the name of month. Best to make a habit of always specifying a locale in date-time work.

The modern approach avoids the troublesome old date-time classes, instead using their replacements, the java.time classes.

```
String input = "May 23 2011 12:20:00" ;
```

Define a formatting pattern to match the input using the [`DateTimeFormatter`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html) class.

The [`Locale`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Locale.html) determines (a) the human language for translation of name of day, name of month, and such, and (b) the cultural norms deciding issues of abbreviation, capitalization, punctuation, separators, and such.

```
Locale locale = Locale.US ;
DateTimeFormatter f = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern( "MMM d uuuu HH:mm:ss" , locale );
```

Your input lacks any indication of time zone or offset-from-UTC. So we parse as a `LocalDateTime`.

```
LocalDateTime ldt = LocalDateTime.parse( input , f ) ;
```

> ldt.toString(): 2011-05-23T12:20:00

---

## About java.time

The [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) framework is built into Java 8 and later. These classes supplant the troublesome old [legacy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legacy_system) date-time classes such as [`java.util.Date`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Date.html), [`Calendar`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Calendar.html), & [`SimpleDateFormat`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html).

The [Joda-Time](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/) project, now in [maintenance mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Maintenance_mode), advises migration to the [java.time](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html) classes.

To learn more, see the [Oracle Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime/TOC.html). And search Stack Overflow for many examples and explanations. Specification is [JSR 310](https://jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=310).

Where to obtain the java.time classes?

- [**Java SE 8**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_8), [**Java SE 9**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_9), and later

  - Built-in.
  - Part of the standard Java API with a bundled implementation.
  - Java 9 adds some minor features and fixes.
- [**Java SE 6**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_6) and [**Java SE 7**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Java_version_history#Java_SE_7)

  - Much of the java.time functionality is back-ported to Java 6 & 7 in [***ThreeTen-Backport***](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp/).
- [**Android**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_(operating_system))

  - The [***ThreeTenABP***](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) project adapts *ThreeTen-Backport* (mentioned above) for Android specifically.
  - See [*How to use ThreeTenABP…*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/38922754/642706).

The [**ThreeTen-Extra**](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/) project extends java.time with additional classes. This project is a proving ground for possible future additions to java.time. You may find some useful classes here such as [`Interval`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/Interval.html), [`YearWeek`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearWeek.html), [`YearQuarter`](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/org/threeten/extra/YearQuarter.html), and [more](http://www.threeten.org/threeten-extra/apidocs/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

Probably It's a problem with a tool you use.
Take a look at:

[Why am I getting a ParseException when using SimpleDateFormat to format a date and then parse it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2967613/why-am-i-getting-a-parseexception-when-using-simpledateformat-to-format-a-date-an)